# MS SQL Bulk Copy Program (BCP) Issue: SQL becomes incapable of serving web pages when carrying out BCP procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

Within MS SQL 2008 we have two seperate mirrored databases each with a number of tables (say DB1 & DB2). The databases are queried by our Web Server to access data for our end clients, with approx half million daily hits.

Every day we update the databases using the BCP utility to insert 2 million+ rows. During the update process on DB1 the web Server switches to query data from DB2. Once DB1 has been updated the Web Server switches back to getting data from DB1, then DB2 is updated using BCP utility. Quite straight forward you’d think.

Our problem is during this transfer the whole of SQL Server database gets jammed/slows down to the extent we receive website timeouts during the transfer. We have ample CPU / Ram capacity.

I have searched extensively but have not been able to find a solution. I am not a database administrator but work as an application developer using SQL server 2008 databases. I would really appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Are you *sure* the web site changes to a different DB? What does, say, sysprocesses say?

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck may be your IO system (disks) - some profiling may help in finding out what the issue really is. Are the databases and logs of DB1 and DB2 on the same physical drives?